# jquery-file-upload plugin css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-file-upload

I'm implementing jQuery-file-upload plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) into a rails app.

I just realized that when:

1. I download the plugin from GitHub.
2. Extract it.
3. Open Basic.html.

That there is no styling (css) being applied. The live online demo version shows styling and is the exact same version I have minus google ads and analytics. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Have you even checked their repo https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css

Comment: Yes. How do I get my buttons to look like the ones he has on the demo site.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. The page relied heavily on a remote BootStrap CSS which was not being loaded.